# Data dictionary logical to physical abbreviated name conversion

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to convert logical data dictionary to a physical (abbreviated) data dictionary - I have given 4 use cases below.

Need help for this psuedo-code / requirement:

```
# empty dict declaration
refDict = {}

# to catch and report on any 'not-found' dictionary words to replace
noMatchFound = {}

# read from a dictionary of comma delimited dictionary
# with open('dictionary.csv') as inputDict:
#     for line in inputDict:
#         busTerm, busAbbr = line.split(',')
#         refDict[busTerm] = busAbbr.replace("\n","")

# sample data dictionary entries
refDict = {
         'user': 'USR',
         'call': 'CALL', 
         'detail': 'DTL', 
         'record': 'REC', 
         'call detail record': 'CDR',
         'count', 'CNT'}


input_string1="user call detail record"
# output should be "USR_CDR"
# noMatchFound - will be empty - since all are matched and replaced

input_string2="user test call detail record"
# output should be "USR_TEST_CDR"
# noMatchFound - should have an entry "TEST" with a refernce to "user test call detail record"

input_string3="user call count detail record"
# output should be "USR_CALL_CNT_DTL_REC"
# noMatchFound - will be empty - since all are matched and replaced

input_string4="user call  detail record count"
# output should be "USR_CDR_CNT"
# noMatchFound - will be empty - since all are matched and replaced
```

So far, I could figure out the code snippet for matching any possible one-single-largest-expression as:

```
import re

# using regular expressions find longest matcing expression
def getLongestSequenceSize(inputStr,  inDict):
    ret_match = ""
    ret_match_len = 0
    ret_abbr = ""
    for inKey in inDict:
        matches = re.findall(r'(?:\b%s\b\s?)+' % inKey.strip().upper(), inputStr.strip().upper())
        if len(matches) > 0:
            longest_match = max(matches)
            if ret_match_len <  len(longest_match):
                ret_match_len = len(longest_match)
                ret_match = longest_match.strip()
                ret_abbr = inDict[inKey]
    return [ret_match.strip(), ret_abbr.strip()]
```

Comment: "Need help" is far too general for StackOverflow.  This is for specific programming problems, not a general program-writing service.  We need you to attack the problem yourself.  Start with a few statements at a time, just one or two tiny steps toward a solution, and print the input and output for each stage, so you know what you're doing.  If you get confused on one of those steps, then post your code and the output you got (including those tracing print statements), and we'll help you over the specific problem point.
See the help documents on what and how to post here.

Comment: @Prune, I disagree. This is a clear question. It is not too general, it is actually too specific. That is its problem, it is *too* specific. He has given enough input/output cases and he explained the problem well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is you start trying to `replace()` from the biggest string in the dictionary and you check every possible replacement given the dictionary, from longer to shorter.

This exactly works as you expected:

```
refDict = {
         'user': 'USR',
         'call': 'CALL',
         'detail': 'DTL',
         'record': 'REC',
         'call detail record': 'CDR',
         'count': 'CNT'}

sorted_ref = sorted( refDict.items(), key=lambda x:len(x[0]), reverse = True )

def do_work(input_string):
    noMatchFound = {}
    rval = input_string[:]
    for key, value in sorted_ref:
        rval = rval.replace(key, value)
    not_founds = [x for x in rval.split() if x.islower()]
    for not_found in not_founds:
        noMatchFound[not_found] = input_string
        rval = rval.replace(not_found, not_found.upper())
    rval = '_'.join( rval.split() )
    return rval, noMatchFound

inputs = ["user call detail record", "user test call detail record",
          "user call count detail record","user call detail record count"]

for inp in inputs:
    print inp
    output, noMatchFound = do_work(inp)
    print output
    print noMatchFound
    print '---'
```

### Output:

```
user call detail record
USR_CDR
{}
---
user test call detail record
USR_TEST_CDR
{'test': 'user test call detail record'}
---
user call count detail record
USR_CALL_CNT_DTL_REC
{}
---
user call detail record count
USR_CDR_CNT
{}
```

Comment: @Prune, actually the second block of the code that initially posted was what I tried to work with - but was not going anywhere..

Comment: @chokkanna Please consider accepting this answer by clicking the tick next to it if it helped you. Thanks.